# Pandas DataFrame behavior differs between hdf and parquet

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I load two identical pandas `DataFrames` from `hdf` and from `parquet`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
from pandas.testing import assert_frame_equal

hdf = "data/h5.h5"
parquet = "data/parquet.parquet"

hdf = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_hdf(hdf))
parquet = pd.DataFrame(pq.read_table(source=parquet, use_threads=False).to_pandas())
assert_frame_equal(hdf,
                   parquet,
                   check_index_type=True,
                   check_column_type=True,
                   check_exact=True)
```

Now I do the following operation

```py
def reset_and_set_index(df):
    ix = df.index.names
    new = df.reset_index()
    new.set_index(ix)
```

and time it.

```py
%timeit reset_and_set_index(hdf)
3.62 s ± 79.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit reset_and_set_index(parquet)
1.92 s ± 14.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Why is the `DataFrame` that was loaded from `parquet` quicker than the one from `hdf`? I would think that both `DataFrames` are in memory after loading and there should not be any difference?

Comment: You might check: Identical deep memory usage?

Comment: Checked it. Identical ....